# How to join either one of two tables that both share a column, and then continue joining?

Tags: mysql, join

Say a user can have two kinds of posts, a self post and external link post. **Both types have their own table.** Each post can have multiple tags. Now I am looking for a query that gives me a list of both a) the tags that have been used in posts in the last X days and b) the users that made those tags (in order to send them an email.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT users.name, users.email, tags.name
FROM users
LEFT JOIN self_posts ON users.id = self_posts.user_id AND self_posts.date < x
LEFT JOIN ext_posts ON users.id = ext_posts.user_id AND ext_posts.date < x
WHERE NOT NULL coalesce(self_posts.id, ext_posts.id)
INNER JOIN tags on ~~either self_posts/ext_posts~~.tag_id = tag.id
```

As you can see, I'm not sure how to make the inner join use either of the two tables for joining the tag table. Would I need to use a subquery for the left joins?

Note: my actual query is more complex than this and needs more subsequent joins. I'm just illustrating the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not get the union of 2 tables first:

```
SELECT users.name, users.email, tags.name
FROM users
join (
  select *
  from self_posts a
  where a.date < x
  union all
  select *
  from ext_posts a
  where a.date < x) a a.user_id = users.id
INNER JOIN tags on a.tag_id = tag.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there a special reason you chose a `UNION ALL` instead of a plain Union? Why would I need the duplicate rows?

Comment: @user371699. Since the 2 tables are storing different types of posts, I assumed there aren't duplicates. If that's not true, then use `union`, otherwise `union all` is faster.

Comment: What if I don't need to use the actual posts themselves, and I'm just "passing through" those tables? In other words, if I select only the `user_id` and `tag_id` columns for the UNIONS, would there ever be a case where I would need the duplicates?

Comment: @user371699, when you need to count of posts including duplicates?

Comment: Good point, didn't think about something like that. Thank you very much for your help! (Side note: I can't seem to type "@Fabricator" to mention you in the comments.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if mySQL supports this, but could this work for you?

```
INNER JOIN tags on self_posts.tag_id = tag.id or external_posts.tag_id = tag.id
```